# configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH error on Debian 5 while installing Python

Tags: debian, command-line, software-installation

I use Debian 5 and I had to update my GCC to 4.9.4. So I build and installed it by myself. Now I need to update Python but I can't to do that because I receive this error:

> configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

Can I link the compiler that I installed to solve this problem?

Also I tried following commands `which gcc` , `which cc` and `which g++` and only last one returned path to g++. Other commands returned nothing.

I downloaded GCC archive, build it and install it

```
../gcc-4.9.4/configure --prefix=/opt/gcc49/ --disable-libsanitizer --disable-libcilkrts
make
make install
```

I just need python 2.6.

Comment: If you are using Debian 5, then you should consider upgrading. Security support stopped in early 2012.

Comment: Where did you install to? What command did you use to install?

Comment: I downloaded GCC archive, build it and install it( ../gcc-4.9.4/configure --prefix=/opt/gcc49/ --disable-libsanitizer --disable-libcilkrts, make, make install). I just need python 2.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/opt/gcc49/bin` is not in your path. You need to add it, or use `stow`.